# Answering a question with a bounty. Update old answer, or start a new answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, bounty

### Background

I have created an update to an answer I gave when there was no bounty. Now there is a bounty.

As you can guess, I want the bounty.

### Question

**Should I update the answer I gave**, which I feel might mean I might not get any of the bounty if the OP does not decide to give out any bounty. **How can I increase my chances of getting the bounty with my new edit?**

- **Update my pre-bounty answer?**
- **Create a new bounty?**

It is well known that this is stated in the help center:

> the highest voted answer **created after the bounty started** with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount.

### That is why I am asking this question

By the way,

- My answer got 2 or 3 upvotes pre-bounty.
- It now got 1 or 2 more upvotes during the bounty period. 4 total upvotes now
- There has been more answers that were given after the bounty started.
- None have upvotes now

### Clarification

Here is an answer (might be deleted because it was found to be Not An Answer by the person asking it after we chatted in the comments). Read the comment section as that explains the issue at hand.

[image]

Comment: one thing worth noticing is that it may not always be the OP who offers the bounty. It may be *someone else* who wants to reward an existing answer. Also, check out the reason the bounty was given. ANO i hope you aren't talking about [THIS POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103191/how-to-read-numberformatexception-error-message) as you can't award a bounty to yourself ;)

Comment: No, not that post. It isn't mine question

Comment: @mehow I checked out your profile and seen your how to debug a small program. What have you tried comment. If you see that a lot, you can link to my answer you linked to....it shows them how to debug...just a thought :)

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification. I think you have to wait for one of the SO developers to pick this up.

Comment: @mehow: Still, it must be flattering you attracted enough attention for someone to go through 40 of your posts *just to downvote*. Ah, and all that work for nothing ... tomorrow they will be gone again, right?

Comment: @mehow OMG, who did that? Plus I just seen now on my laptop that those were links that you had in your profile. On my phone it looked just like text.

Comment: @Jongware what about the **feature** tag. I don't know when moderators can use and when they should not use it

Comment: Personally, if the bounty is legitimately up for grabs, I think I would edit my answer and then leave a comment @ing the bounty person, saying, "I have expanded my answer. If it still doesn't solve your problem, please let me know what happened when you tried my answer or why you didn't try my answer." That way, you're legitimately offering more help.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that; however, my idea is what happens if the OP does not give out the bounty and it is automatically awarded. I take it my answer will not get it regardless of what I do

Comment: Then I would assume he/she didn't get his/her question answered and isn't willing to respond to people who try to help. I wouldn't sweat it and move on.

Comment: It looks more like none of the answers will get the bounty. During the grace period, the bounty can be manually awarded. If not, half of it it goes to the highest scoring answer with a score of **2 or greater** posted after the bounty started. There's also automatic awarding of an accepted answer, but I'm not sure if that happens during the grace period. The help isn't totally clear on that point. Hm. It might make sense to file a feature request so that existing answers that receive 2 or more upvotes during the bounty period are also eligible for the automatic half.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly why I posted my question. I feel like that should be clarified and there should be a **feature-request** for updated pre-bounty answers so they can get 50% of the  bounty automatically

Comment: That isn't entirely clear from your question. I would (at minimum) add a "Feature Request" section to your question detailing your feature request. In my opinion, answers that pre-exist the bounty should at least still be required to receive the required number of up-votes *during* the bounty period. (This is different than it already having them before the bounty; it must receive them on top of whatever it already had.) Although, I would post it as a separate meta post. Otherwise, it's somewhat of an abuse of the up-votes you have on this question prior to adding [tag:feature-request].

Answer (score 7):

Leave your answer.

If you leave your answer, two things could happen:

1. Vivek gives you the bounty, and you already have 50 from your answer. Total: **100**.
2. Vivek gives someone else the bounty or it expires without being awarded, but you already have 50 reputation from your answer. Total: **50**.

If you delete your answer and write a new one, four things could happen:

1. Vivek doesn't give you the bounty, you don't get any upvotes, and the bounty expires without getting awarded. Total: **0**.
2. Vivek doesn't award the bounty to anyone, but you get enough upvotes to earn half of it it automatically. Total: probably around **50**.
3. Vivek gives you the bounty, but you don't get any upvotes. Total: **50**.
4. Vivek awards the bounty to you, and you get a few upvotes. Total: probably around **70**.

Comment: But you missed my point. Should that answer be amended to my old answer, or should a create a new one that I know has the possibility of getting the automatic bounty if the OP does not award it. Btw, I do feel like the OP will award the bounty, but I could not help but think what if the OP did not and I, or someone else, created a great answer. They would not get anything, no matter how many votes they got for their pre-bounty (but now updated) answer. That seems wrong, and I think a feature-request is needed

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski you are the owner of your answer. You can edit it as much as you want. You can even wipe all the old content and provide a new content, it is doable but you should somewhat maintain the content of your prev answer. Also, you can always use a separator by posting `----` in a single line and then provide the *new* answer.

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski And it looks like leaving your answer was the right choice. An upvote, accept. and bounty. Total: **125**.